# Magnons and creation and annihilation operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, quantum-spin, spin-chains

I am trying to obtain the spin waves (or magnons) arising from a 1D Heisenberg spin-chain, namely
\begin{equation}
{\cal H}=-J\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf{S}_i\cdot \mathbf{S}_{i+1} 
\end{equation}
After using the Holstein-Primakoff transformation,
\begin{align}
S_{+,j}\rightarrow \sqrt{2S}a_j \\
S_{-,j}\rightarrow \sqrt{2S}a_{j}^\dagger
\end{align}
I obtain the following Hamiltonian
\begin{equation}
H=-J S^2 N-SJ\sum_j \left(a_j a_{j+1}^\dagger+ a_{j}^{\dagger}a_{j+1} -a_{j}^\dagger a_j-a_{j+1}^\dagger a_{j+1}\right) 
\end{equation}
If we consider a periodic system, we can solve the following Hamiltonian using $a_{j}^{\dagger}=\sum_k \frac{e^{-ikx_j}}{\sqrt{L}}a_{k}^{\dagger}$, with $x_j=jl$ which yields

\begin{align}
H&=-J S^2 N-SJ\sum_k \left(e^{-ikl}a_k a_{k}^\dagger+ e^{ikl}a_{k}^{\dagger}a_{k} -2a_{k}^\dagger a_k\right)\\
&=-J S^2 N-SJ\sum_k \left[e^{-ikl}(1+ a_{k}^\dagger a_k)+ e^{ikl}a_{k}^{\dagger}a_{k} -2a_{k}^\dagger a_k\right]\\
&=-J S^2 N-SJ\sum_k e^{-ikl}-2SJ\sum_j \left[\cos(kl)-1\right]a_{k}^\dagger a_k
\end{align}

The thing is, except the term $\sum e^{ikl}$, my results match with the literature -- so I started thinking about this term, and how to "get rid of it". For instance, if we use the relation $[a_j,a_{j+1}^\dagger]=0$ within the second Hamiltonian, I obtain a new Hamiltonian given by
\begin{equation}
H=-J S^2 N-SJ\sum_j \left(a_{j+1}^\dagger a_j + a_{j}^{\dagger}a_{j+1} -a_{j}^\dagger a_j-a_{j+1}^\dagger a_{j+1}\right) 
\end{equation}
which after using $a_{j}^{\dagger}=\sum_k \frac{e^{-ikx_j}}{\sqrt{L}}a_{k}^{\dagger}$ results in
\begin{equation}
H=-J S^2 N-2SJ\sum_k \left[\cos(kl)-1\right]a_{k}^\dagger a_k
\end{equation}

So I arrived to the conclusion that $\sum_k e^{ikl}$ must be zero, otherwise the results do not agree. But the point is that this is sum is not zero, so I cannot see where I have messed up. Any thoughs? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think the sum $\sum_{k}{e^{ikl}}$ is not $0$? Given $N$ sites in the spin chain, $k$ takes the value of ${2 \pi \over Nl}$, $2\big({2 \pi \over Nl}\big)$, $3\big({2 \pi \over Nl}\big)$,..., $N\big({2 \pi \over Nl}\big)$, or any equivalent sequence modular to it, so yes, $\sum_{k}{e^{ikl}}=0$.

Comment: Hint: Geometric series. This yields a representation of the Kronecker delta.

Comment: @AndyChen since we have negative and positive $k$, we can transform the sum into $\sum_{k>0}\cos(ikl)=\sum_{k>0}\cos(n\frac{2\pi}{Nl}l)=\sum_{n>0}\cos(n\frac{2\pi}{N})\neq0 $

Comment: @sined Use that for $n\in \mathbb Z$  we have that $e^{ixn} = \left(e^{ix}\right)^n$ and note that the sum of interest is the partial sum of the geometric series...

Comment: @sined That still looks like it should sum to zero for all $N>1$. Are you sure you're summing over all allowed momenta?

Comment: That worked, thank you!